# Submitting to SP List, Input string was not in correct format error JavaScript

Tags: list, javascript

I am getting the error, "Input list was not in correct format error"

My sharepoint list has single text fields so i cannot see the problem

```
  function savingsdatick(varid) {
  //Get Current Tabs before submission
  var allTicksForSave = {};
  $(".thischeck").each(function () {
   allTicksForSave[$(this).attr("id")] = $(this).is(":Checked")
 });
  console.log("So...")
  console.log(allTicksForSave)

  var Tickbox1 = "Tickbox1";
  var Tickbox2 = "Tickbox2";
  var Tickbox3 = "Tickbox3";
  var Tickbox4 = "Tickbox4";
  var Tickbox5 = "Tickbox5";
  var Tickbox6 = "Tickbox6";
  var Tickbox7 = "Tickbox7";
  var Tickbox8 = "Tickbox8";
  var Tickbox9 = "Tickbox9";
  var Tickbox10 = "Tickbox10"
  var Tickbox11 = "Tickbox11";
  var Tickbox12 = "Tickbox12";
  var Tickbox13 = "Tickbox13";
  var Tickbox14 = "Tickbox14";
  var Tickbox15 = "Tickbox15";
  var Tickbox16 = "Tickbox16";
  var Tickbox17 = "Tickbox17";
  var Tickbox18 = "Tickbox18";
  var Tickbox19 = "Tickbox19";
  var Tickbox20 = "Tickbox20";
  var Tickbox21 = "Tickbox21";
  var Tickbox22 = "Tickbox22";
  var Tickbox23 = "Tickbox23";
  var Tickbox24 = "Tickbox24";
  var Tickbox25 = "Tickbox25";
  var Tickbox26 = "Tickbox26";
  var Tickbox27 = "Tickbox27";
  var Tickbox28 = "Tickbox28";
  var Tickbox29 = "Tickbox29";
  var Tickbox30 = "Tickbox30"; 


      var varid = localStorage.getItem("projectnewTitle");
      var currentStorm = document.getElementById("dale3").innerHTML;
      var siteUrl = _spPageContextInfo.webServerRelativeUrl;
      var clientContext =  SP.ClientContext.get_current();
      var oList = clientContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('SecurityDesignAssuranceLeft');
      this.oListItem = oList.getItemById(currentStorm)
        if(allTicksForSave.SDALEFTBOX0) oListItem.set_item('Tickbox1', 'True');
        if(allTicksForSave.SDALEFTBOX1) oListItem.set_item('Tickbox2', 'True');
        // if(allTicksForSave.SDALEFTBOX2) oListItem.set_item(Tickbox3, "True")
        // if(allTicksForSave.SDALEFTBOX3) oListItem.set_item(Tickbox4, "True")
        // if(allTicksForSave.SDALEFTBOX4) oListItem.set_item(Tickbox5, "True")
        // if(allTicksForSave.SDALEFTBOX5) oListItem.set_item(Tickbox6, "True")
        // if(allTicksForSave.SDALEFTBOX6) oListItem.set_item(Tickbox7, "True")
        // if(allTicksForSave.SDALEFTBOX7) oListItem.set_item(Tickbox8, "True")
        // if(allTicksForSave.SDALEFTBOX8) oListItem.set_item(Tickbox9, "True")
        // if(allTicksForSave.SDALEFTBOX9) oListItem.set_item(Tickbox10, "True")
        // if(allTicksForSave.SDALEFTBOX10) oListItem.set_item(Tickbox11, "True")
        oListItem.update();
    clientContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQuerySucceeded4), Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFailed4));
    function onQuerySucceeded4() {
    alert("Hi")
  }

  function onQueryFailed4(sender, args) {
    alert("Failed" + args.get_message())
  }
}
```

Comment: Are there mandatory fields in the list, where you are not setting any values? And by default it is taking a null/empty string?

Comment: Unfortunately not, i know the Title Field is always mandatory but this is set, I am unsure what else it could be? any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you confirm  that the `currentstorm` variable contains a valid integer, and not any extra html.

You might need to use innerText instead.

Comment: Hi James thanks for making me check this, storm was not a valid integer, so when I was trying to get item id, it was throwing this error. What I did instead was rest API to get SharePoint ID row and then got item ID this way :)

Comment: Glad you got it sorted. May you please Mark as Answer or upvote, so it can benefit others.